# Is there a characterization of a convex polygon in terms of polar coordinates of its vertices?

Tags: discrete-geometry

Suppose the n points ${{v}_{1}},{{v}_{2}},...,{{v}_{n}}$ are vertices of a "convex polygon" in the plane and their polar coordinates are $({{r}_{1}},{{\theta }_{1}}),({{r}_{2}},{{\theta }_{2}}),...({{r}_{n}},{{\theta }_{n}})$ , (polar coordinates with respect to an interior point O of the polygon called the center).
The question is what properties or algebraic equations must be satisfied by ${{r}_{i}}$ and ${{\theta }_{i}}$ in order that they "characterize" a convex polygon in the plane.?

Comment: guys i found something : Convexity is equivalent to the function r(θ):[0,2π)→R2  being well-defined and satisfying the condition
|r(λθ1+(1−λ)θ2)|≥|λr(θ1)+(1−λ)r(θ2)|

for all θ1,θ2 and λ∈(0,1)

Comment: and also a curious inequality in Eggleston book "Convexity " page 53....

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=Ees7AAAAIAAJ&q=page+53#v=onepage&q=polar%20&f=false